# JFrog CLI can't set properties on an artifact in JFrog Artifactory for the first property name and using SSH key examples for multi property search

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

**JFrog Artifactory:** 5.8.4 Professional.

**JFrog CLI:** 1.12.1

I'm using [the official documentation of JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) to set few properties on an artifact that's available in Artifactory repo.

- NOTE: I don't want to use `Artifactory AQL` for now and trying to get this working using `jfrog` cli.

I successfully configured the CLI client (the file `~/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf` with entries for authentication using either username/password and with an API Key was created successfully).

For setting properties on an artifact, I referred the following example:

```
jfrog rt sp "generic-local/*.zip" "a=1;b=2,3"
```

and ran the following command (in a free-style Jenkins job):

```
$ jfrog rt sp --server-id="artifactory-dev-instance" --url=${ARTIFACTORY_URL} ${REPO}/${FILE_PATH}/${FILE_NAME} -- props="release=${RELEASE};VERSION=${VERSION};PIPELINE_VERSION=${RELEASE}_${VERSION}_${BUILD_NUMBER};fileType=automated-file;PROJECT=${PROJECT}"
```

This command exited successfully without giving an error and applied all the properties with expected values except the first property `release=${RELEASE}`.

**Question:** Why `jfrog rt sp` is not applying the `release` property on the artifact while all others properties got successfully applied with correct values.

Actual variables values don't matter as I can see other properties getting applied successfully in the given Artifactory instance (ARTIFACTORY_URL), on the target file (sitting in a repo/path/file) and respective properties with their values.

Comment: did the value of the `RELEASE` variable was successfully populated as a part of the `PIPELINE_VERSION` property?

Comment: @JBaruch, Hell yea! ?- The title of this post after the edit is misleading now. It's setting properties but not the first one. Seems like there's some bug in `jfrog` cli i.e. it's not setting the first property being passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this proves it actually (**bug** part in `jfrog` cli). re-add that first property i.e. add the missing first property twice and it works for all properties (including the first one) while giving properties to be added.

Now `release` property is getting applied as well.

```
$ jfrog rt sp --server-id="artifactory-dev-instance" --url=${ARTIFACTORY_URL} ${REPO}/${FILE_PATH}/${FILE_NAME} -- props="release=${RELEASE};release=${RELEASE};VERSION=${VERSION};PIPELINE_VERSION=${RELEASE}_${VERSION}_${BUILD_NUMBER};fileType=automated-file;PROJECT=${PROJECT}"
```

or

```
$ jfrog rt sp --server-id="artifactory-dev-instance" --url=${ARTIFACTORY_URL} ${REPO}/${FILE_PATH}/${FILE_NAME} -- props="release=${RELEASE};VERSION=${VERSION};PIPELINE_VERSION=${RELEASE}_${VERSION}_${BUILD_NUMBER};fileType=automated-file;PROJECT=${PROJECT};release=${RELEASE}"
```

NOTE: While setting properties `jfrog rt sp`, you can specify multiple values for the same property name using `,` i.e. `--props="prop1=value1;prop2=value22,prop2=value23;prop3=value3"` but during `jfrog rt s` (search), you can't use `,` (if you use `,` or `;` at all for matching a property for more than 1 possible values, `jfrog rt s --prop="..."` is not going to give you all the results as it'll pick only the last value and override all other previous values for that given property).

ALSO, using `jfrog` cli --server-id="..." and --url="Artifactory URL" (as listed above) can be used in a **more secure way** if you use SSH key.

Example of using JFROG with SSH key (for better authentication) doesn't require username/password or server-id at command line (which requires ~/.jfrog/jfrog.conf file):

Just create your SSH pub/private key. Add pub key for the user (running the command in Artifactory wide/repo wide settings), then set JFROG_URL variable as:

`JFROG_URL="ssh://artifactory-develop:1339"`

and then simply run:

For setting properties on an artifact:
`jfrog rt sp --ssh-key-path=/home/${USER}/.ssh/id_rsa --url=${JFROG_URL} ...same command as above for sp command`

or for searching

`jfrog rt s --ssh-key-path=/home/${USER}/.ssh/id_rsa --url=${JFROG_URL} ...same command as above for s searching artifacts` (see JFROG cli help on their documentation site).

JFROG cli does NOT support 'AND' and 'OR' within `--props="...."` section for a given property i.e. if you want to search for an artifact where a property `prop1` contains more than one value, then `jfrog` cli as shown above which uses `--props="....."` won't work.

For that, you have the use JFrog file search schema and use `--spec ~/somefile.json` option or curl command with `-T file.json`.

**NOTE**: The json file (syntax) for opening `{` and `}` is different when you use `jfrog` (with --spec file.json) and when you use `curl` with `-T file.json`

**Let's see how to use with `curl` command first.**

Create a `curl-aql.json` file which contains the following (as an example):

```
items.find( 
           { "repo": { "$eq" : "libs-snapshot-local" }}, 
           { "@yourCustomProperty1": { "$match" : "someValue1" }},
           { "@yourCustomProp2": { "$match" : "anotherValue2" }},
           { "@moreCustomProps3": { "$match" : "string_or_number_or_alnum" }},
           { "$or":[ { "@customPropertyWhichHasMultipleValues" : "PASS", "@customPropertyWhichHasMultipleValues" : "UNSTABLE" } ]}
          ).include("*", "@customProperty5iWantAQLToReturnToMeBack", "@yourCustomProperty1","@yourCustomXProp","@yourCustomYProp")
```

**NOTE:** All properties which you create (i.e. which Artifactory doesn't give you for free like 'name', 'repo') MUST be prefixed with an **@** character in AQL for you'll find a weird error mesg about something wrong with format at character # 74 or 75.

Then run this `curl` command (user id is: **123456** and password is contained in `$p`):

`curl -u123456:$p -H 'content-type: text/plain' -X POST http://artifactory-develop:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql -T ~/curl-aql.json`

This is less secure but works well (if you define and **MASK** the password variables in Jenkins and call your script). Still, I'd rather use `jfrog` `--props="..."` for simple searches or `--spec jsonfile` (for more complex searches or other operations what `jfrog` CLI supports) using MORE secure `--ssh-key-path=/your/home/.ssh/your_private_key_id_rsa` way using `--url=$JFROG_URL` (SSH url).

In `jfrog` if you want to use Artifactory's **AQL** capabilities, then try this:

Create a file `jfrog-aql.json` containing:

```
{ 
    "files": [
    {
        "aql": 
        {
            "items.find":  
            {
                "repo": "libs-snapshot-local" , 
                "@yourCustomProperty1": { "$match" : "ABC1.22.33" },
                "@yourCustomProperty2": { "$match" : "Project1" },
                "name": { "$match" : "ArtifactX-*.json" },
                "@yourCustomProperty3": { "$match" : "2.*" },
                "@yourCustomProperty4": { "$match" : "some-manifest-file" }
            }
        },
        "sortBy" : ["created"],
        "sortOrder" : "desc",
        "limit" : 1
    }
    ]
}
```

**NOTE:** this json file has `jfrog` cli's `--spec jsonfile` requirements and have a little different syntax than what we used in the json file (during `curl` run).

Now you can run it using `jfrog` via:

```
jfrog rt s --ssh-key-path=/home/${USER}/.ssh/id_rsa --url=${JFROG_URL} --spec ~/jfrog-aql.json
```

**Finally** found a better AQL where you can use `$and` or `$or` for multi-search on values of a single property (you can add more by tweaking it). See AQL file here:

(**NOTE**: It's better to use `$qa` than using `$match` when the value is known i.e. hard-coded and it's better to use `simple form` (see how `repo` is used below. Use or `$match` makes sense when your value has `*` in it, see how `name` property is used below):

```
{ 
    "files": [
      {
        "aql": 
        {
            "items.find":  
            {
                "repo": "libs-snapshot-local" , 
                "@yourCustomProperty1": "ABC1.22.33",
                "@yourCustomProperty2": "Artifact1",
                "name": { "$match" : "ArtifactX-*.json" },
                "@yourCustomProperty3": { "$match" : "2.*" },
                "@yourCustomProperty4": "some-manifest-file",
                "$or": [
                    {
                       "@customProperty5": "Hard-Coded-Known-Value1",    
                       "@customProperty5": "Hard-Coded-Known-Value2"
                    }
                ]    
            }
        },
        "sortBy" : ["created"],
        "sortOrder" : "desc",
        "limit" : 1
      }
    ]
}
```

NOTE: See related post [Chef Berks Install (Berkshelf) Timesout contacting Artifactory repository (Faraday Timeout / Actor Crashed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029165/chef-berks-install-berkshelf-timesout-contacting-artifactory-repository-farad/55033459#55033459) if you use `Chef` and `berks install` (for finding and locking cookbooks versions for stable repetitive deployments, using `berks apply` (lock-in versions of cookbooks) and using `knife create <Chef-Env> -c ...` for creating Chef Environments / Files).